# How to manually select video and audio format while using youtube-dl?

Tags: youtube-dl

If I like to choose -f 248 for video and -f 171 for audio, how should I do it? I remember there is a single line command that can merge manually selected audio and video after downloading.

Answer (score 24):

`youtube-dl -f 248+171 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=???` will do the trick